# Why does this code keep returning a 'has no attribute' error?

Tags: python

My code is as follows, where `sdl2ext.Entity` is a third party class.

```
class Grid(sdl2ext.Entity):
    def __init__(self, world):
        self.w = 3
        self.h = 3
        super(Grid,self).__init__()

    def dump(self):
        print(self.w)

def run():
    world = sdl2ext.World()
    g = Grid(world)
    g.dump()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

The specific error that I get is with the line `print(self.w)`:

`AttributeError: object ''Grid'' has no attribute ''w''`

Is this something to do with not initialising the underlying base object, `sdl2ext.Entity`?

Comment: Why are you initializing the superclass after setting the private attributes?

Comment: Because of the answer given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670020/python-class-inheritance-attributeerror-why-how-to-fix . Specifically the definition for the `CastSpell` class given in the accepted answer.

Comment: You misunderstand. Why are you initializing the superclass *after* setting the private attributes, instead of before?

Comment: @BartoszKP could you elaborate on that at all?

Comment: @Ignacio, in the accepted answer for that linked question, the superclass is initialised after the private attributes. I thought it was ok to do that.

Comment: That completely depends on what the superclass does and how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should read [the code of the paren class](https://bitbucket.org/dangillet/py-sdl2/src/e776e6d56e53061df34462a0743f8875a47cd876/sdl2/ext/ebs.py?at=default#cl-48). The class overwrites many special methods, including `__getattr__` which likely has something to do with your problem.

Comment: `__getattr__` is only called as a *fallback*; `self.w` is first looked up in the instance `__dict__`, `__getattr__` is only consulted if it is not found there.

Comment: See the [`__getattr__` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__): *Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for `self`)*

Comment: So @Martijn are you saying that __getattr__ is not the problem?

Comment: @patchwork: I am saying `__getattr__` **cannot** be the problem.